# Highstock chart.getSVG() does not export all details

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock V 1.2.5.

I am using `chart.getSVG()` which returns HTML. But, I do have `addPlotBand` and `addPlotLine` which seems not be exported with this method.

EDIT:

This seems known issue.

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1114

Is there any way to export these along with `chart.getSVG()` ?

Comment: Isn't the issues fixed already? http://jsfiddle.net/HeJ2e/ seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed as I see, in the newest master branch

http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js

http://github.highcharts.com/master/modules/exporting.src.js

Comment: Let me check with latest version. BTW, Isn't this in `exporting-src.js`